# How to explode a cookie and put result in a multidimensional-array

Tags: php, arrays, cookies, multidimensional-array, explode

I´m new to coding so please be kind :)

Working on an online market place where people can upload real estates that are for sale or rent I want to establish a favorite list with cookies. I already managed to store the offering_id and the offering_type in a cookie using

```
setcookie("$flat_rent_id", $flat_rent_id . "__" . "$offering_type", time() + (86400 * 30), '/');
```

and construct an array explodedCookiesArray using

```
// Construct array of exploded cookies
$h = -1;
$i = -1;
foreach($_COOKIE as $COOKIE => $value) {
    $h++;
    $i = -1;
    $explode = (explode("__", $value, 2));
    foreach ( $explode as $item ) {
        $i++;
        $explodedCookiesArray[$h][$i] = $item . " " ;
    }
}
```

When I print the array using

```
// Print the constructed array "explodedCookiesArray
echo "explodedCookiesArray";
for ($i=0; $i <= count($_COOKIE); $i++){
    echo "<br>";

    for ($j=0; $j <= count($_COOKIE); $j++){
        echo $explodedCookiesArray[$i][$j];

    }
}
echo "<br>";
```

I get the output

```
explodedCookiesArray
378b94ed20765e354ec9790832800ed6 
Offering5ce890ed7f11d house_rent
Offering5ce8935b812f6 house_sale
Offering5ce8f86bbda11 flat_sale
Offering5ce93dfdcae32 house_rent
Offering5ce9411388315 flat_rent
```

If I use

```
print_r($explodedCookiesArray);
```

I get the output:

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [0] => 378b94ed20765e354ec9790832800ed6 ) 
[1] => Array ( [0] => Offering5ce890ed7f11d [1] => house_rent ) 
[2] => Array ( [0] => Offering5ce8935b812f6 [1] => house_sale ) 
[3] => Array ( [0] => Offering5ce8f86bbda11 [1] => flat_sale ) 
[4] => Array ( [0] => Offering5ce93dfdcae32 [1] => house_rent )
[5] => Array ( [0] => Offering5ce9411388315 [1] => flat_rent ) )
```

Nevertheless the command

```
if (isset($explodedCookiesArray[1][1])) {
    echo $explodedCookiesArray[1][1] . "<br>";

    if ($explodedCookiesArray[1][1] == "house_rent") {
        echo "Hello";
    } else {
        echo "Goodbye";
    }
}
```

outputs the following:

```
house_rent
Goodbye
```

Does anyone have an idea why?
I´d be very thankful for all kind of help!

Comment: Try using print_r($explodedCookiesArray) to see the arrays contents.

Comment: @Dammeul just tried and added the output to the question text, thank you. Can you have another look? I still don´t see the error...

Comment: how strange.. it should work from the looks of it... I've tried it out here, get the same output and it's working https://3v4l.org/ktJN3...

Comment: Where are you doing the IF? Is there anything that could be changing the value further up in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you say first:

```
$explodedCookiesArray[$h][$i] = $item . " " ;
```

And then you say:

```
if ($explodedCookiesArray[1][1] == "house_rent")
```

There is no space character in the comparison.

---

This code is far more verbose than it needs to be though. If I'm understanding your data correctly, one line in a `foreach` loop is all you need:

```
// test data
$_COOKIE = [
    "PHPSESSID"             => "378b94ed20765e354ec9790832800ed6",
    "Offering5ce890ed7f11d" => "Offering5ce890ed7f11d__house_rent",
    "Offering5ce8935b812f6" => "Offering5ce8935b812f6__house_sale",
    "Offering5ce8f86bbda11" => "Offering5ce8f86bbda11__flat_sale",
];

$explodedCookiesArray = [];
foreach ($_COOKIE as $c) {
    $explodedCookiesArray[] = explode("__", $c);
}

if ($explodedCookiesArray[1][1] == "house_rent") {
    echo "Hello";
} else {
    echo "Goodbye";
}
```

Output:

```
Hello
```

---

Really, what you should be doing is storing this as a [serialized](https://php.net/serialize) array of values instead of multiple cookies. Or store the list in a database and keep only a unique identifier in the cookie.

Comment: Thats it! Thanks for helping me to find the error and the tips regarding the code structure.